# Integrating Facebook Group stream on an external website

Tags: facebook, plugins, stream, integrate, facebook-group

I'm a member of a club that has a Joomla website and a Facebook group. Only about one third of the club's members are active on Facebook, and we'd like the rest to be able to follow the discussions taking place on Facebook from the club's external website. Of course, users without a FB profile won't be able to post comments themselves, which is fine.

So what I need is basically the functionality of the Like Box plugin, only for a group instead of a page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Is this possible? I've only been able to find this discussion about the topic, but it's old and the links don't work anymore: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=48722

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Wallflux RSS feed from wallflux.com and publish it on zour J! site?

Comment: This is probably better for extracting the feed as RSS though: https://apps.facebook.com/groups_to_rss/